# Partition of finite volume set into subsets of positive volume is at most countable.

Tags: measure-theory

I found this problem in Makarov and Podkorytov's Real Analysis: Measures, Integrals and Apliccations.

In exercises 1-3, $v$ is a finite volume defined on an algebra **A** of subsets of a set *X*.

(3). Show that every partition of *X* into subsets of positive volume is at most countable.

This is what I have done so far:

Let **B** $ = \{A_{\alpha}: \alpha \in I\}\subseteq $ **A**, be a partition of X such that $v(A)>0$ for every $A\in$ **B**. For every $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ let us define:

$$ 
B_{n} = \{ A\in \textbf{B} \hspace{0.5mm} : v(A)>1/n \}
$$

It is clear from the definition that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}B_{n} \subseteq$ **B**. On the other hand, given *A* $\in$ **B**, we have $v(A)>0$. By the Archimedean Property, we can find $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $v(A)>1/n$, so that $A\in B_{n}.$ This shows that **B** $\subseteq$ $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}B_{n} $ and hence

$$
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}B_{n} = \mathbf{B}.
$$

Now, I would like to prove that each $B_n$ is finite or at most countable, for then the conclusion would follow, but I don't know how to proceed. I think this is related with the finite additivity of $v$ and the fact that $v(X)<\infty$. Could someone help me finish this problem? This is the definition of a volume according to the book: [definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE6VN.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Big hint: Since the sets in $\mathbf{B}$ are disjoint, we have that for each $n\geq 1$,

$$\frac{|\mathbf{B}_n|}n<\sum_{S\in\mathbf{B}_n}v(S)\leq v(X)<\infty$$

so each $\mathbf{B}_n$ must be finite.